# How to skin Windows Forms components entirely?

Tags: .net, winforms, skin

I would like to create my own components and skin them entirely so that they do not use any style from Windows. I am using Mono and I want the skin to look the same on each platform.

Are there articles/tutorials/references that explain how to build your own button component that looks the way you want it to?

Comment: I can't help suggesting that you use WPF...

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann too bad Mono does not support that.

Comment: You picked a bad one to get started with, the Button class doesn't support custom painting.  At least the .NET version.  The underlying OS interface is very different, the odds that your custom Mono code will work across platforms are pretty slim.  Adopting the native OS theme is otherwise considered a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is taking credit for someone else's work, but this looks like a good one:
[Custom Bitmap Button](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9734/Custom-Bitmap-Button-Using-C)

It is handling all the rendering in its own paint events (including the border and the gradient backgrounds). It's also supporting every button state, including the typically ignored "focused" state.